How can I kill spid with talend
When I try to 'Kill Spid' with Talend it doesn't work.
How can I handle this sitiuation?
When I try, Talend returns the result as below and does not close the session.
"kill command cannot be used inside user transaction"
Thanks for your advise :)
Error
I create an sp and its include 'KILL @SPID'.After that , I try to run this sp with TDBRow compenent. But I got error.

Show your screen, list down the component you use. What is SP here mean? Store procedure?
